# Django template: Extract field from model queryset object

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

In a Django template, I am fetching the newest comment using:

```
{{ blog.comments.all|dictsort:"created_at"|last }}
```

where `blog` is a instance of the `Blog` model, `comments` is the `related_name` with a `ForeignKey` to the `Comment` model.

This is the equivalent of

```
blog.comments.all().order_by("created_at").last()
```

**Question:** How can I get the `text` field for the comment in the template?

In the view I can do this using:

```
blog.comments.all().order_by("created_at").last().text
```

If I try:

```
{{ blog.comments.all|dictsort:"created_at"|last.text }}
```

I get a:

> Could not parse the remainder: '.text' TemplateSyntaxError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag:

  ```
  {% with newest_comment=blog.comments.all|dictsort:"created_at"|last %}
      {{ newest_comment.text }}
  {% endwith %}
  ```
- [`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) decorator:

  *models.py*

  ```
  from django.utils.functional import cached_property

  class Blog(models.Model):
      @cached_property
      def newest_comment(self):
          return self.comments.order_by('created_at').last()
  ```

  *template.html*

  ```
  {{ blog.newest_comment.text }}
  ```
- context:

  ```
  context['newest_comment'] = blog.comments.order_by('created_at').last()
  return render(request, template, context)
  ```
- [`latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#latest) method:

  *models.py*

  ```
  class Comment(models.Model):
      class Meta:
          get_latest_by = 'created_at'
  ```

  *template.html*

  ```
  {{ blog.comments.latest.text }}
  ```

Comment: Are you sure that the first one (`with`) shouldn't be `{% %}`?

Comment: @Jedi Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use the "with":

```
{% with blog.comments.all|dictsort:"created_at"|last as lastcomment %}
  {{ lastcomment.text }}
{% endwith %}
```